# Android development toggling TextView visibility

Tags: java, android

Im having some trouble with setting textview to invisible/visible.

basicly i want this to happen when an on/off button has been clicked.

what i did is kind of like

```
textview.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
textview.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

when i try executing this the emultor says that the app has stopped unexcpetedly

Comment: Could you please add a stacktrace?

Comment: Did you 1. set your content to the layoutfile with the TextView? (`setContentView(R.layout.main);`), and 2. find your view by id? (`findViewById(R.id.mytextview);`)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you building this from XML or programmatically?

I would make it with an XML file then when the Activity runs change the property. Be sure to use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` before you try to get the TextView with `findViewById(...)`.

Call `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` on the TextView to hide it.

Call `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to on the TextView to show it.

I have an example that does something like this. You can see the code here: https://github.com/ethankhall/Morse-Messenger/blob/master/src/com/kopysoft/MorseMessenger/Translate.java

Answer (score 2):

Without more code or a stack trace, it's hard to say, but it sounds like you haven't initialized the text view. Here's how to do it:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
```

Where 'tv_text' is the id of the textview as defined in the xml layout file.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Read about DDMS and logcat to obtain a stacktrace and to see what the problem is: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html

This is what you are looking for:
[image]

Comment: You could also try running it from Eclipse in debug mode and see where it stops in the code.